# Hibernate mapping Exception:One2Many

Tags: hibernate

Simple example of hibernate

have pojo Employee EmployeeDetails and Department

o2o between employee and employeeDetails and  one to many between department and employee

**Employee.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")

public class Employee {


private Long employeeId;
private String firstname;   
private String lastname;
private EmployeeDetail employeeDetail;
private Department department;

//Constructers
public Employee() {

}


public Employee(String firstname, String lastname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

//For Employee
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="employee_id")
public Long getEmployeeId() {
    return employeeId;
}

public void setEmployeeId(Long employeeId) {
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
}

@Column(name="firstname")
public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

@Column(name="lastname")
public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}


//For Department

public Department getDepartment() {
    return department;
}

public void setDepartment(Department department) {
    this.department =department;
}

//For EmployeeDetails
@OneToOne(mappedBy="employee", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public EmployeeDetail getEmployeeDetail() {
    return employeeDetail;
}

public void setEmployeeDetail(EmployeeDetail employeeDetail) {
    this.employeeDetail = employeeDetail;
}
```

}

**Department.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DEPARTMENT")

public class Department
{

private Long departmentId;

private String departmentName;

private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<Employee>(0);

//Constructers
public Department() {

}

public Department(String departmentName) {
    this.departmentName = departmentName;
}

public Department(String departmentName,Set<Employee> employees) {
    this.departmentName = departmentName;
    this.employees=employees;
}

//For Department
 @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name="department_id")
public Long getdepartmentId() {
    return departmentId;
}

public void setdepartmentId(Long departmentId) {
    this.departmentId= departmentId;
}

 @Column(name="DEPT_NAME")
public String getdepartmentName() {
    return departmentName;
}

public void setdepartmentName(String departmentName) {
    this.departmentName= departmentName;
}

//For Employee
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="employee_id")
public Set<Employee> getEmployee() {
    return this.employees;
}

public void setEmployee(Set<Employee> employees) {
    this.employees = employees;
}


}
```

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.hibernateDemo.Department, at table: EMPLOYEE, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(department)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1358)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1849)
    at util.HibernateUtil.createSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:17)
    at com.hibernateDemo.StoreData.main(StoreData.java:16)
```

want the solution to remove this exception

Comment: Uhmm, what was the question?

Comment: The answer is in the question: you have a ManyToOne between Employee and Department. So, where is your @ManyToOne annotation? Also, the methods should be `getDepartent` and `setDepartment`, with a capital D. And please read the Hibernate documentation to know how to map a bidirectional OneToMany association.

Comment: i have an annotation @OneToMany in Department.java

Comment: But what is missing is the ManyToOne annotation in Employee.